# Differential entropy of $\Gamma$

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function, entropy, gamma-distribution

Let $X \sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ be gamma distributed random variable with probability distribution function

$$
f_{X}(x)=\frac{\beta^{\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)},\;x>0
$$

where, $\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}dx$ is Euler's gamma function. Prove that,

$$
\begin{split}
H_{g}(\alpha)& =-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)\log[f_{X}(x)] dx \\
& =\log[\Gamma(\alpha)]+\alpha -\frac{\log(\alpha)}{2}+(1-\alpha)\psi(\alpha)
\end{split}
$$

where, $\psi(\alpha)=\frac{\Gamma'(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$.

Comment: Please improve formatting, show your efforts and fix the typo in the second equation: $f_X$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$ only, hence the integral giving the entropy cannot be an integral over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, the integration is on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, but I defined the entropy function in general whose limits is on $\mathbb{R}$. It reduces to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ based on the fact that $0log(0)=0$.

Comment: if $f_X$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$ only, what is the meaning of $$ \int_{-\infty}^{0}f_X(x)\log f_X(x)\,dx $$ ?

Comment: $f_{X}(x)=0$ for $x \in (-\infty,0)$. $f_{X}(x)$ is pdf function. So, normally we define the region where it is non-zero and the rest is zero. Isn't it?

Comment: All right, but $f_X(x)=0$ for $x<0$ wasn't stated in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how it's equivalent to the solution below, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution),  (infobox, entropy), the final expression above should be $\log[\Gamma(\alpha)] + \alpha - \log (\beta) + (1-\alpha) \psi(\alpha)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting rid of the syntactic sugar, we have to compute:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}\log\left(x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}\right)\,dx = - \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\beta^\alpha}+(\alpha-1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}\log x\,dx$$

where:

$$J(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}\log x\,dx = \frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}\,dx $$
is:
$$ J(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\beta^{\alpha}}=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\beta^{\alpha}}\cdot\frac{d}{d\alpha}\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\beta^{\alpha}}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\beta^{\alpha}}\left(\psi(\alpha)-\log \beta\right)}. $$